# Jest + React: IntersectionObserver mock not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, intersection-observer

In my component.test.js, I tried mocking the IntersectionObserver by doing something like this:

```
const mock = ()=>({
    observe: jest.fn(),
    disconnect: jest.fn()
});
window.IntersectionObserver = jest.fn().mockImplementation(mock);


describe("Component", ()=>{
    it("test 1", ()=>{
        render(<Component/>);
        ...
    }
});
```

My component.js looks something like this (it does that infinite pagination thing):

```
//ref to last item loaded >> load more items once it enters view
const observer = useRef();
const lastEntryRef = useCallback((node)=>{
        ...
        observer.current.disconnect(); //ERROR LINE
    }
    ...
);
```

When I run the tests, however, I get `TypeError: observer.current.disconnect is not a function`; same goes for `observer.current.observe()` if it runs. I tried testing it inside the it() block of component.test.js itself by instantiating an IntersectionObserver and then calling those methods and the same message showed when I re-ran the tests, so the errors look unrelated to how IntersectionObserver was set up in component.js. Am I not mocking IntersectionObserver correctly? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you to replace the `arrow function` for a `normal function` because you need to use the [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) to create an `InterceptionObserver` object:

```
const mock =  function() {
  return {
    observe: jest.fn(),
    disconnect: jest.fn(),
  };
};

//--> assign mock directly without jest.fn
window.IntersectionObserver = mock;
```

The you can check if `window.InterceptionObserver.observe` has been called.